# How can I remove inter-cell spacing between cells created by Print statement in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a Mathematica 6 simulation that prints out rows of results now-and-then with a command similar to the following (with different numbers obviously):

```
Print[GridBox[{{Cell["123456", Background->Pink],Cell["789101",Background->Pink]}}] // DisplayForm];
```

As you can well imagine this results in a table with an arbitrary number of rows as the simulation progresses. My problem is how to get the pink boxes printed by each statement above to 'touch' the one below so that I get pink 'columns' of numbers (in other words for the cells created by the above Print statements, I want to remove all inter-cell spacing). If you run something like this:

```
Print[GridBox[{{Cell["123456", Background->Pink],Cell["789101",Background->Pink]}}] // DisplayForm];
Print[GridBox[{{Cell["123456", Background->Pink],Cell["789101",Background->Pink]}}] // DisplayForm];
Print[GridBox[{{Cell["123456", Background->Pink],Cell["789101",Background->Pink]}}] // DisplayForm];
```

together in one cell you'll see what I mean. So far I have tried using CellMargins (for eg: CellMargins->{{20,20},{0,0}}) but to no avail. The only way I've been able to get what I want is to set CellMargins within the Option Inspector by first selecting the cells, going to Format -> Option Inspector -> Cell Options -> Display Options and from there reseting CellMargins to something like {{60,Inherited},{-1,-1}. I obviously would prefer to do this with code,... Is that possible?

Terry

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use Print[] a new Cell is created.   This is somewhat not desirable if what you want is a growing table.

There are several ways to just update the exiting table you have, for example, PrintTemporary[], Print[Dynamic[...]] or Monitor[].

Personally I would use `Print[Dynamic[...]]`.   For example, you can use this to print out the table before the simulation:

```
table = {{"Column1", "Column2"}};
Print[Dynamic[
    GridBox[Map[Cell[#, Background -> RGBColor[1, 0.5`, 0.5`]] &, 
        table, {2}], RowSpacings -> 0] // DisplayForm]];
```

This will print out a table with just the column titles.  Then during simulation all you have to do is update this table, and the output will update

```
AppendTo[table, {"123456", "78910"}];
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you need to change the `StyleData` for `"Print"` cells.  This is most easily done by creating a custom Stylesheet.

- With your Notebook open and focused go to Menu **Format** > **Edit Stylesheet...**.
- In the field **Enter a style name** type in `Print` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  A new Cell will be created in the area below.  You can select that Cell and use the Option Inspector to change its properties as you wish.
- Close the Style Definitions window, and observe that your options are now used for all `"Print"` cells (as generated by `Print`).

---

According to the comments it is acceptable to use a customized print function therefore you do not need to make dynamic changes to the environment or modify style sheets.  Example:

```
gridPrint[x__] :=
 CellPrint @ ExpressionCell[Row[{x}], "Print", CellMargins -> {Inherited, {-1, -1}}]
```

Now:

```
gridPrint[GridBox[{{Cell["123456", Background->Pink],Cell["789101",Background->Pink]}}] // DisplayForm];
gridPrint[GridBox[{{Cell["123456", Background->Pink],Cell["789101",Background->Pink]}}] // DisplayForm];
gridPrint[GridBox[{{Cell["123456", Background->Pink],Cell["789101",Background->Pink]}}] // DisplayForm];
gridPrint[GridBox[{{Cell["123456", Background->Pink],Cell["789101",Background->Pink]}}] // DisplayForm];
gridPrint[GridBox[{{Cell["123456", Background->Pink],Cell["789101",Background->Pink]}}] // DisplayForm];
```

[image]

If this fails in your application please give me an example and I will attempt to correct it.

---

Please ask your future questions on the dedicated *Mathematica* StackExchange site:

[image]

Comment: Hmm,... But what if you want it changed for only certain Print commands? Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: @Terry Sorry, I didn't see you comment until now.  The simplest is probably to use your own print function, e.g. `myPrint`, calling `CellPrint` with the options you want.  Is this acceptable to you?  If so I will add code to my answer.

Comment: @Terry Done.  Please test it.